# No me pinta la API :( (nada en expo)

Tags: api, lista, react-native, vscode, expo

Estoy tratando de consumir una API, pongo un botón y al darle clic quiero que me mande la data de la API pero no me pinta nada en pantalla solo me aparece el botón y no sucede nada cuando le doy clic, estoy usando expo, es de mis primeros codigos, apenas estoy aprendiendo el leguaje de programación, ojalá me pudiera ayudar.

Les dejo el código que estoy haciendo.

```
import axios from "axios";
import {View, Button, FlatList, StyleSheet, StatusBar} from "react-native";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const baseURL = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1";

export default function App() {

    const descargarUsuarios = useState([]);
          useEffect(() => {
          axios.get(baseURL).then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
          });
          }, 
          []);

          const renderList = ({ item }) => {
            return (
              <View style={styles.item}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>{item.id}</Text>
              </View>
            );
          };

    const listado = (() => {
        <FlatList
        data={descargarUsuarios}
        renderItem={renderList.item}
        //keyExtractor={ }
        /> 
    })    

    return(
        <View>          
        <Button
            color="pink"
            title="USUARIOS"
            onPress= {() => listado}/>                    
        </View>)

};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight || 0,
  },
  item: {
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 32,
  },
});
```

Comment: por qué no pruebas la herramienta de Postman, es buena si trabajas con API´s. Ahí puedes probar si te el error es parte tuyo o de la API.

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas la documentación sobre el hook de [useState](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) porque no lo estás usando correctamente. Deberías tener: `const [descargarUsuarios, setDescargaUsuarios] = useState([]);` y dentro del `useEffect` deberías llamar a `setDescargaUsuarios(response.data)` con la respuesta de la API